# JSON and Quirks mode

Tags: json, firefox, standards

I am creating a script which outputs JSON. It has the correct content type (application/json). When viewed in Firefox, the "Page Info" says it is in Quirks mode. My JSON passes through a validator with no errors or warnings.

Does Firefox always display JSON in Quirks mode, or is there something I can put in my output to elevate it into Standards mode?

I'm asking this question as a matter of curiousity rather than because it will destroy my application, but I would rather all program output be as compliant as possible with any existing recognised protocol or standards.

Comment: Quirks mode is only relevant for HTML or CSS, not JSON. There is no standard or normal way to display JSON data. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode.

Comment: Thanks, read that page before I asked - it didn't say anything specifically about JSON, which was why I posted. :-). The first answer I got expands on your comment and seems to explain the reasoning more fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox generates an HTML document to render a pretty formatted version of JSON. That document triggers Quirks mode.

Since you aren't maintaining the HTML document, you don't need to worry about the rendering mode.